# Custom Oauth2 Authorization Server - AccessDeniedException: Access is denied

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I try to write my own custom oauth2 based Authorization Server for my web application. I planned it something like this:
[image]

I want to authenticate through login form available in my angular app. Than I want to access with my angular app protected resources using JWT Token generated by my authorization service. Currently I am unable to login to my application, because server responds with exception:

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176) [spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_192-ea]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_192-ea]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_192-ea]
```

I enabled debug mode and logs before exceptions looks like this

```
    2018-11-22 18:31:18.110 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
2018-11-22 18:31:18.110 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/oauth/token'
2018-11-22 18:31:18.110 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key']
2018-11-22 18:31:18.110 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/oauth/token_key'
2018-11-22 18:31:18.110 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']
2018-11-22 18:31:18.110 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/oauth/check_token'
2018-11-22 18:31:18.110 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2018-11-22 18:31:18.110 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2018-11-22 18:31:20.309 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2018-11-22 18:31:20.310 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2018-11-22 18:31:20.311 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2018-11-22 18:31:20.311 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2018-11-22 18:31:20.311 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /login' doesn't match 'GET /logout
2018-11-22 18:31:20.311 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2018-11-22 18:31:20.311 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
2018-11-22 18:31:20.311 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2018-11-22 18:31:20.311 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /login' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2018-11-22 18:31:20.311 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2018-11-22 18:31:20.311 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /login' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2018-11-22 18:31:20.311 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2018-11-22 18:31:20.311 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter'
2018-11-22 18:31:20.312 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor         : Token not found in headers. Trying request parameters.
2018-11-22 18:31:20.312 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor         : Token not found in request parameters.  Not an OAuth2 request.
2018-11-22 18:31:20.312 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter : No token in request, will continue chain.
2018-11-22 18:31:20.312 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2018-11-22 18:31:20.313 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2018-11-22 18:31:20.314 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2018-11-22 18:31:20.314 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@458c3963: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2018-11-22 18:31:20.314 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2018-11-22 18:31:20.314 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2018-11-22 18:31:20.314 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2018-11-22 18:31:20.315 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /login; Attributes: [#oauth2.throwOnError(authenticated)]
2018-11-22 18:31:20.315 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@458c3963: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2018-11-22 18:31:20.319 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@11646bb9, returned: -1
2018-11-22 18:31:20.324 DEBUG 8476 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
```

My configuration classes looks like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class OAuth2Config(
        private val dataSource: DataSource,
        private val authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager,
        private val userDetailsService: UserDetailsService,
        private val bCryptPasswordEncoder: BCryptPasswordEncoder
) : AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Bean
    fun tokenStore(): JdbcTokenStore {
        return JdbcTokenStore(dataSource)
    }

    @Bean
    fun oauthAccessDeniedHandler(): OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler {
        return OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler()
    }

    @Bean
    fun accessTokenConverter(): JwtAccessTokenConverter {
        return JwtAccessTokenConverter()
    }

    override fun configure(oauthServer: AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer) {
        oauthServer
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder)
    }

    override fun configure(clients: ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer) {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource)
    }

    override fun configure(endpoints: AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer) {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
class ServerSecurityConfig(
        private val userDetailsService: UserDetailsService
) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Bean
    fun bCryptPasswordEncoder(): BCryptPasswordEncoder {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
    }

    @Bean
    override fun authenticationManagerBean(): AuthenticationManager {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean()
    }


    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder())
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.cors() 
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin() 
                .and()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    }

}
```

Comment: is CORS enabled ? Have debuggd your browser ? Right click browser  => inspect elelemtn => console.  Doest it work with Postman ?

Comment: @georgesvan Cors is taken care off (google chrome add on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem lied in my lack of understanding of Oauth 2.0. Based on [baeldung blog articles](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs) and [baeldung github project](https://github.com/pokemzok/spring-security-oauth) I was able to create my own solution which is available [on my github](https://github.com/pokemzok/parkandrest-kotlin)

Answer (score 1):

Change your configuration with this

```
List<String> permitAllEndpointList = Arrays.asList(
                AUTHENTICATION_URL,
                REFRESH_TOKEN_URL);
    http.cors() 
    .and()
    .csrf().disable()
    .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin() 
    .and()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(permitAllEndpointList.toArray(new String[permitAllEndpointList.size()]))
    .permitAll()
```

This will give permission to auth and refresh token urls. You can add new urls to list.